# using node js request library to perform a curl request

Tags: curl, request

I want to convert a curl request to node js normal get request.
I tried to use request library but it never works but when i use the curl one it works very good on my command line.

Here is my curl request that I am trying to convert:

```
curl -u keyid:keysecret https://api.mybitx.com/api/1/balance
```

so it takes two things the keyid and the keysecret those two parameters I change them with the my own ones.

and here is my node js code to achieve this.

```
const request = require('request');

app.get('/api/luno/getBalance', function() {
  return request.get(
      'https://api.mybitx.com/api/1/balance', {
        'auth': {
          'keyid':'my keyid',
          'keysecret': 'my key',
        },
      }
      , function(error, response, body) {
        console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
        console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
        console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.
      });
});
```

if you can see I use request the library to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it should be done :

```
app.get('/api/luno/getBalance', function(req, res, next) {
  request({
    uri: config.MYBITX_API_URL,
    auth: {
      username: config.MYBITX_API_USERNAME,
      password: config.MYBITX_API_PASSWORD
    }
  })
    .on('error', next)
    .pipe(res)
});
```